# What does 'pending_reclamation' state mean?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-pak-for-data

When I try to delete the *Cloud Object Storage* service in my *Cloud Pak for Data as a Service* account, I get this message:

`An unexpected error occurred while attempting to delete service instance: Unexpected response code: 500 (Instance is in pending_reclamation state. Use API to reclaim the instance.)`

What does this error mean?  What should I do to really delete this service?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/hyper-protect-dbaas-for-mongodb?topic=hyper-protect-dbaas-for-mongodb-what-new#dec-2020:

> When you delete a service instance, it's disabled (pending reclamation) rather than deleted completely. You can restore a deleted service instance with no data loss within the retention period of seven days. You can also choose to permanently delete it. See [Deleting service instances](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/hyper-protect-dbaas-for-mongodb?topic=hyper-protect-dbaas-for-mongodb-data-security#service-delete).

This seems to be true for all IBM Cloud services, not just MongoDB. Using the [command line interface](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_commands_resource#ibmcloud_resource_reclamations), I was able to actually delete the Cloud Object Storage service I had.